# Office server automation failed while calling "CopyPicture" on some computers

Tags: vba, excel

We have wrote an application with C++/Qt which reads some data from multiple excel files and then generate a word report. We have used benefits of Office automation server to read/find and copy data from excel files and write them into a single word file.

The application works fine without any significant problem in my office computers. Yesterday I've decided to copy the app into my laptop which has same OS and office version. After running the app, it seems that somethings wrong my OS/Office. None of the data are copied into word file. After debugging I've figured out that the app actually can read/write office files but failed to call **CopyPicture** method of automation!!!

I wanted to copy the range as picture, so I have used "CopyPicture" method. but it seems that the vba fails to call copyPicture on my laptop.

I'll be very appreciated for any hints. Thank you

Comment: Copy picture uses the clipboard. I've never had warm fuzzy experiences with the clipboard. Make sure the clipboard on your PC is functioning.

Comment: @CodyG. Clipboard is working. Even I've coded vba in the excel vba editor and 'copyPicture' is working there. but in the C++ application the copyPicture is not working on my laptop.

Comment: Can copyPicture paste a picture to the same document while excel is running normally? I.e. does it not work on your laptop at all?

Comment: @CodyG. I've found the problem and it is with excel docs which are used to copy data from. When embeddedCharts are used in sheets, then, 'CopyPicture' will be failed on that sheets!!!! very odd! and I don't know really why!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem and it's with excel docs which are used to copy data from. In these files, there are some embeddedCharts. after removing these charts the code works fine!!!! (very odd). Anyway, I've tried to make excel file visible in order to see if the operation goes well or not. After running (with embeddedCharts) the code worked fine (more odd!!)

```
excel->dynamicCall("Visible", true );
```

I don't know the reason but with making excel file visible, the error with copyPicture is gone!